# Deleting the lowest value in a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote this and somehow it's ending up deleting all my left side on the tree not only the most left leaf.

I can't find my mistake, can someone help?

```c
struct Node *delMin(struct Node **root)
{
    struct Node *current = *root;
    struct Node *b4Current;

    while ((current->m_ls) == NULL) {
        b4Current = current;
        current = current->m_ls;
    }

    if ((current->m_rs) == NULL) {
        b4Current->m_ls = 0;
        free(current);
    } else {
        b4Current->m_ls = current->m_rs;
        free(current);
    }

    return *root;
}
```

Comment: what did you find when you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: nothing , all went just as planned then after this method I printed inorder to see my tree and half of it gone...

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org/) (so that we can compile it as is and observe the issue).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i6Febeyu

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your function.

```
struct Node *delMin(struct Node **root)
```

You take a pointer to node pointer as argument and return the new head. That is unnecessary. Returning the head is only useful if it isn't updated otherwise. Your pointer-to-node-pointer approach caters for that (well, it should, but it doesn't), so that the return value is free for other information.

```
    struct Node *b4Current;
```

Here, you define an uninitialised pointer. You should initialise it to `NULL` to idicate that the current node, the head, doesn't have a parent. Otherwise the pointer will be a garbage value that is likely to cause undefined behaviour.

```
    while ((current->m_ls) == NULL) {
        b4Current = current;
        current = current->m_ls;
    }
```

Here, your condition is wrong: You want to go left as long as there is a pointer, but you do something else: You go left if there isn't anywhere to go! When the head has a left child, `current` will stay at the head. Otherwise, it will be `NULL`, which will cause havoc when you try to dereference it later.

```
    if ((current->m_rs) == NULL) {
        b4Current->m_ls = 0;
        free(current);

    } else {
        b4Current->m_ls = current->m_rs;
        free(current);
    }
```

The two branches of the `if` are really the same, if you think about. It's a bit like saying: `if (x == 0) y = 0; else y = x;`.

But you need an `if` here, namely to distinguish between the case that `current` is the head or not. In the former case, you should update `*head`, the latter case is what you have already written.

You should also catch the case that you can't remove a node from an empty list.

So:

```
void delMin(struct Node **root)
{
    struct Node *current = *root;
    struct Node *b4Current = NULL;

    if (current == NULL) return NULL;

    while (current->m_ls != NULL) {
        b4Current = current;
        current = current->m_ls;
    }

    if (b4Current == NULL) {
        *root = current->m_rs;
    } else {
        b4Current->m_ls = current->m_rs;
    }

    free(current);
}
```

But since you are passing a pointer to your head node anyways, you could simplify the function to:

```
void delMin(struct Node **root)
{
    if (*root == NULL) return;

    while ((*root)->m_ls != NULL) {
        root = &(*root)->m_ls;
    }

    struct Node *old = *root;

    (*root) = (*root)->m_rs;
    free(old);
}
```

You may have some ugly `(*root)`s here, but you do away with a lot of auxiliary variables and `if` statements. The idea is that you add one level of indirection by iterating with a pointer to node pointer. `*root` takes the role of your `b4Current` and `(*root)->m_ls` is your `current`, except that `*root` starts with a sensible initial value, namely the root node.

Comment: i must do it struct Node *delMin(struct Node **root) (as define in the work) ill try to do what you said and come back with results

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in your while loop condition. You want to be traversing the left side of the tree while current->m_ls != NULL, otherwise you will delete the entire left side of you tree.