# Building a Huffman tree from a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, huffman-code

I am trying to build a huffman tree out of binary search tree. Sadly my code is crashing (Segmentation fault (core dumped)).

This is how the `struct` is defined:

```
struct Node
{
  unsigned char m_ch;
  int m_freq;
  struct Node *m_ls,*m_rs;
  struct Node *m_hls,*m_hrs;
};
```

`delMin` is passed a double pointer to a binary search tree, and deletes from it the leftmost leaf unless it reaches a Node with `m_ch==0` and return the deleted Node

I can't find my mistake

```
struct Node *delMin(struct Node **root)
{
    struct Node *current = *root;
    struct Node *b4Current;

    if (current == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (current->m_ls != NULL)
    {
        if (current->m_ch == 0)
            break;

        b4Current = current;
        current = current->m_ls;
    }

    if (current->m_ch == 0)
        b4Current->m_ls = NULL;
    else
    {
        if (b4Current == NULL)
            *root = current->m_rs;
        else
            b4Current->m_ls = current->m_rs;
    }

    return current;
}


struct Node *huffman(struct Node *root)
{
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *tempRoot;
    struct Node *huffmanTree;

    while (root->m_ch != 0)
    {
        left = delMin(&root);
        right = delMin(&root);
        tempRoot = createNode((left->m_freq) + (right->m_freq), 0);
        tempRoot->m_hls = left;
        tempRoot->m_hrs = right;
        insertTree(&root, tempRoot);
    }

    huffmanTree = tempRoot;
    return huffmanTree;
}
```

EDIT: Added code for the `insertTree` function called by `Huffman`

```
void insertTree(struct Node **root,struct Node *n)
{
  if (!*root)
  {
    *root=n;
    return;
  }
  if(n->m_freq<(*root)->m_freq)
  {
    insertTree(&((*root)->m_ls),n);
  }
  else
  {
    insertTree(&((*root)->m_rs),n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or insert `puts()` calls to determine the exact location where the fault occurs. Then track the associated logic and figure out where the problem is.

Comment: A likely candidate for a segmentaion violation is `while (root->m_ch) ...`: After removing the last node from the tree, `root` is `NULL` and you can't dereference it with `->`. So just `while (root)` should be okay.

Comment: If `root` is a node such that `current->m_ls != NULL` and `current->m_ch==0` the while loop of `delMin()` is immediately exited. Since  `current->m_ch==0`, the test is entered and `b4Current->m_ls=NULL;` is executed. But `b4Current` is not initialized : a segmentation fault can be triggered.

Comment: while (root) starts an inf loop @MOehm

Comment: Okay, I see you are making things overly complicated by inserting a dummy node with `m_ch == 0`. But you don't show how you build the binary tree.

Comment: the binary tree is built base on the m_freq value . @MOehm

Comment: Yes, I know, otherwise you couldn't build a Huffman tree.

Comment: so what do you mean by "how you build the bin tree"? @MOehm

Comment: I also get a mild sense of déjà vu. I've corrected [the `getMin` for a user called Raz yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219315/deleting-the-lowest-value-in-a-binary-search-tree/30220147#30220147). Why don't you update that function according to my suggestions? The cose I posted works. (Or why do you bother to post hzere at all if you are not going to read the answers?)

Comment: I miss read what i had to do , so I made it return the deleted Node , and today I realised i must see when m_ch is 0 to make the algoritem possable @MOehm you can see it is what you told me with some addtions

Answer (score 1):

In `delMin` this code section

```
if (current->m_ch == 0)
    b4Current->m_ls = NULL;
else
{
    if (b4Current == NULL)
        *root = current->m_rs;
    else
        b4Current->m_ls = current->m_rs;
}
```

there is no guarantee that `b4Current` is not NULL.

Consider the case where the root node has `m_ch == 0` and `m_ls == NULL`. You will take the `if` branch and dereference `b4Current`.

You need to initialize `b4Current` with `NULL` and check for it before any dereference.

You also need to ensure `root` itself is non-null before initializing `current = *root` in `delMin` or dereferencing it in `huffman`

These should all be initialized to NULL

```
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
struct Node *tempRoot;
struct Node *huffmanTree;
```

and it is possible, again, to never enter the while loop, leaving `tempRoot` unset causing a potential segFault in the caller of `huffman` when you return its value.

Comment: i still get the sefFault with your seggestions

Comment: Is there a chance it's in `InsertTree`, which you're not showing us?

Comment: I've added it to your post. I suspect there are opportunities to segfault in other (still missing) code, but what you've shown us suggests you need to look closely at all your pointer handling.